# Cant run openCV sample FaceDetection Application

Tags: opencv

I am a beginner for learning opencv, I want to make a face dection for a photo ,
I use a sample, but get this error ,how can I fix this?
[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVXzw.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Some context would be helpful for us to help you with that: First, openCV is available for multiple languages. As you seem to be using c++, please also add this to your questions tag list. Then it would be interesting to know which sample (link?) you are using. If you modified it, please show us your code. Finally please do not post errors or code as images (or links). Images tend to get taken down, making the question useless for future readers. Better use a quotation or code block and provide the error in textual form. This also allows other users to better search for them.

Answer (score 0):

I really agree with @m00am but from the nature of the error I can say your images doesn't get to your function (most probably because of wrong path of images)